# USPS API Sept. 7 2014 Web Tools Release

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, api, usps

I just received this email from USPS

> > "September 7, 2014 USPS will be implementing changes and additional features to the Web Tools APIs. Detailed release notes are available
> >     on the USPS Web Tools home page at www.usps.com/webtools.
>
> The CAT/staging environment is now available to developers for
>   testing using your Web Tools user ID and the following URLs:
>
> ```
> Secure APIs: https://stg-secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll
> Non-secure APIs: http://stg-production.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll
> ```
>
> To ensure we have the best contact information for you, please take a
>   few moments to complete our four-question contact form by clicking the
>   following link: Web Tools Customer Contact Form
>
> Please email us at WebTools@usps.gov if you have any issues or
>   questions. You can also reach us on twitter @USPSWebTools for updates
>   and announcements.
>
> Thank you,"

I have CE v 1.7.0.2 is there a Magento CE USPS API patch or update that must be done or will it not effect us like the Jan 26, 2014 USPS update had no effect...but this one appears to have more to it...if anyone knows the answer please respond...hopefully someone from Magento or they will post a message here.
Thanks

Comment: it will not effect you, I did this and it works fine without a patch Bella

Answer (score 1):

**Magento has not announced any releases to cover the changes of Sept. 7, 2014 at this time.** We'll hope it's not like last year where the July 28, 2013 announcement left us scrambling over the next week to bring USPS service back online.

However, this is of concern. -> **USPS API RateV3** ends on Sept. 28, 2014

Following are patches (July 2013) for Magento Community Edition to support **USPS API RateV4**:

If you installed these patches last year, you're done, if you installed a third party module that allowed you to use `Priority Mail` and `Priority Mail Express` with the RateV3 API (didn't install these patches) then you need to apply them before Sept. 28.

1.8.x.x can ignore the following.

Versions **prior** to 1.7.x.x require applying a shipping methods patch first so Magento will support **USPS API RateV4**. The second API Upgrade patch supports the changes to the USPS `Priority Mail` and `Priority Mail Express` postage methods.

```
Target Magento Release             Upgrade of Shipping Methods Patch  USPS API Upgrade Patch
                                   (if not previously applied)
Magento Community Edition 1.7.x.x  Not Required                       PATCH_SUPEE-1868_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.sh
Magento Community Edition 1.6.2.0  MAGEBP-706_CE_1.6.2.0_v4.patch     PATCH_SUPEE-1868_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.sh
Magento Community Edition 1.6.1.0  MAGEBP-706_CE_1.6.1.0_v4.patch     PATCH_SUPEE-1868_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.sh
Magento Community Edition 1.6.0.0  MAGEBP-706_CE_1.6.0.0_v4.patch     PATCH_SUPEE-1868_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.sh
Magento Community Edition 1.5.1.0  MAGEBP-706_CE_1.5.1.0_v4.patch     PATCH_SUPEE-1868_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.sh
Magento Community Edition 1.5.0.1  MAGEBP-706_CE_1.5.0.1_v4.patch     PATCH_SUPEE-1868_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.sh
Magento Community Edition 1.4.2.0  MAGEBP-706_CE_1.4.2.0_v4.patch     PATCH_SUPEE-1868_CE_1.4.2.0_v1.sh
```

Available from the following links:

**USPS API RateV4** patch (must be applied first)

```
http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MAGEBP-706_CE_1.4.2.0_v4.patch
http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MAGEBP-706_CE_1.5.1.0_v4.patch
http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MAGEBP-706_CE_1.6.2.0_v4.patch
```

API Update Specific to 1.4.2.0:

```
http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/PATCH_SUPEE-1868_CE_1.4.2.0_v1.sh
```

API Update for all others up to 1.7.x.x

```
http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/PATCH_SUPEE-1868_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.sh
```

**Users of 1.7.x will probably have already installed this above patch so they could ship by `Priority Mail` and `Priority Mail Express` back in early August 2013.**

If you merely installed third party modules that supported using `Priority Mail` and `Priority Mail Express` **with the RateV3 calculator** on 1.6.x.x and previous, **you will have to apply** both the `Shipping Methods Patch` and `USPS API Upgrade Patch`

Comment: Above is why we are adamant that no link only answers be allowed. You cannot find this information on the Magento official website as they conveniently "An eBay Inc. Company"d it out of existence with link rot. It's really sad with the official support website can't keep important stuff alive -> http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/magento-community-edition-alert-important-patch-for-usps-api/ However, the resource download links still work, fingers x'd.